# How to loop Ajax response in blade

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm fetching data using Ajax from the database now I want to loop the response I get from the database, but I'm stuck, have no idea on how I can loop this. Any help would be appreciated.

//This is how I loop using Laravel(I want to loop like this with Ajax)

```
@foreach(range(1,5) as $i)
@if($total >0)
@if($total >0.5)
 <div>Full star</div>
@else
<div >Half star</div>
@endif
@else
 <div >Empty star</div>
@endif
<?php $total--; ?>
@endforeach
```

//This is the response from Ajax which displays total number from database

```
<span id="mycount"></span>
```

Ajax

```
function getCount() {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: '{{route('live.review')}}',
success: function(data) {
   $('#mycount').html(data);
   setTimeout(getCount, 1000);
}
});

}
getCount();
```

Comment: What is the data you are receiving over Ajax call?

Comment: Is the rating(numbers, from 1 to 5) so user might rate a product with 5 or 4 or 2 stars@ Sandeep Modak

Comment: is it json data you are receiving or just html/text. add response in your query too.

Comment: I receive Json data and is being displayed in blade like this `<span id="mycount"></span>`  so this line output is the number if it 5 then it displays 5 @SandeepModak

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Blade to loop through an Ajax request. Blade templates are rendered server-side and jQuery runs on the clients browser. You have to use javascript to do this.

One way to do this would be:

```
success: function(data) {
   for(item of data){
     $('#mycount').append(`<div>${item}</div>`)
   }
}
```

I have no idea what you are trying to achieve or what type of data you are getting but this is something to get you started.

Comment: I tried your way but at least is kinda working but got stuck in for loop , I want to use a loop like this `@foreach(range(1,5) as $i)` but in Ajax. @dsat

Comment: Your code seems be an infinite loop (it recurses forever). Don't call getCount() from inside itself. Other than that, I'd need to see the data you are getting to be of more help.